# How to DRY up some code

Tags: jquery, dry

Suppose on an eCommerce site, there are 2 ways to add an item, one from the catalog, one from the cart...

```
<btn class="add_item" data-type="cart"></btn>
<btn class="add_item" data-type="catalog"></btn>
```

Because these functions both are about adding an item, there's a lot of overlap. However, because they occur in different places, there are some differences as well. Is there a convention in terms of which code format follows standard principles (e.g., SRP, DRY, etc)?

I'm specifically asking about a convention, because I'm trying to write more "standard" code. FWIW, historically I've always done Option B and I feel like that's eventually led me down the path of very very long functions with nested if/thens that's been confusing.

Option A

```
$(".add_item[data-type='cart']").click(function() {
  doSomethingUniqueToCart();
  doSomethingSharedToAdd();
})

$(".add_item[data-type='catalog']").click(function() {
  doSomethingUniqueToCatalog();
  doSomethingSharedToAdd();
})
```

Option B

```
$(".add_item").click(function() {
  if ($(this).data("type") == "cart") {
    doSomethingUniqueToCart();
  } else {
    doSomethingUniqueToCatalog();
  }
  doSomethingSharedToAdd();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it's going to more efficient to attach specific listeners than to attach generic ones and have to query for info to distinguish cases.  I'd probably do something like,

```
$(".add_item[data-type='cart']").click(doSomethingUniqueToCart);
$(".add_item[data-type='catalog']").click(doSomethingUniqueToCatalog);
$(".add_item").click(doSomethingSharedToAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have option C for you:

```
var functionList = {
"cart":doSomethingUniqueToCart,
"catalog":doSomethingUniqueToCatalog
}
$(".add_item").click(function() {
  functionList[$(this).data("type")]();
  doSomethingSharedToAdd();
});
```